# Select option from an object to display next options in next select

Tags: javascript, select

Trying to make 3 selects.

In the first one, you choose the **region**, then in the second select, u can choose **town** from this region and then in 3rd select **hotel** from this town.

The region select in working ok but the town select is broken, so do hotel would be broken too. I want to do this without jQuery

```js
var region = document.getElementById('region');
var town = document.getElementById('town');
var hotel = document.getElementById('hotel');
    
    
var json = {
        'regions':{
            'region1':{
                'Town1_1':['hotel1_1_1', 'hotel1_1_2'],
                'Town1_2':['hotel1_2_1', 'hotel1_2_2'],
                'Town1_3':['hotel1_3_1', 'hotel1_3_2'],
                'Town1_4':['hotel1_4_1', 'hotel1_4_2'],
            },
            'region2':{
                'Town2_1':['hotel2_1_1', 'hotel2_1_2'],
                'Town2_2':['hotel2_2_1', 'hotel2_2_2'],
                'Town2_3':['hotel2_3_1', 'hotel2_3_2'],
                'Town2_4':['hotel2_4_1', 'hotel2_4_2'],
                'Town2_5':['hotel2_5_1', 'hotel2_5_2'],
            },
             'region3':{
                'Town3_1':['hotel3_1_1', 'hotel3_1_2'],
                'Town3_2':['hotel3_2_1', 'hotel3_2_2'],
                'Town3_3':['hotel3_3_1', 'hotel3_3_2'],
                'Town3_4':['hotel3_4_1', 'hotel3_4_2'],
                'Town3_5':['hotel3_5_1', 'hotel3_5_2'],
                'Town3_6':['hotel3_6_1', 'hotel3_6_2'],
            },
        } 
    }
    var key = Object.keys(json.regions);
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = key[i];
        region.appendChild(opt);
    }
    
    region.addEventListener('change', selectRegion);
    
    function selectRegion() {
    
        if (region == 'region1'){
            var key1 = Object.keys(json.regions.region1)
            for (let i = 0; i < key1.length; i++) {
                var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
                opt1.innerHTML = key1[i];
                town.appendChild(opt1);
            }
            
        }
        else if(region == 'region2'){
            var key2 = Object.keys(json.regions.region2)
            for (let i = 0; i < key2.length; i++) {
                var opt2 = document.createElement('option');
                opt2.innerHTML = key2[i];
                town.appendChild(opt2); 
            }
            
        }
        else {
            var key3 = Object.keys(json.regions.region3)
            for (let i = 0; i < key3.length; i++) {
                var opt3 = document.createElement('option');
                opt3.innerHTML = key3[i];
                town.appendChild(opt3);   
            }
            
        }
    }
```

```html
<select id='region'></select>
<select id='town'></select>
<select id='hotel'></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var region = document.getElementById('region');
var town = document.getElementById('town');
var hotel = document.getElementById('hotel');

var json = {"regions":{"region1":{"Town1_1":["hotel1_1_1","hotel1_1_2"],"Town1_2":["hotel1_2_1","hotel1_2_2"],"Town1_3":["hotel1_3_1","hotel1_3_2"],"Town1_4":["hotel1_4_1","hotel1_4_2"]},"region2":{"Town2_1":["hotel2_1_1","hotel2_1_2"],"Town2_2":["hotel2_2_1","hotel2_2_2"],"Town2_3":["hotel2_3_1","hotel2_3_2"],"Town2_4":["hotel2_4_1","hotel2_4_2"],"Town2_5":["hotel2_5_1","hotel2_5_2"]},"region3":{"Town3_1":["hotel3_1_1","hotel3_1_2"],"Town3_2":["hotel3_2_1","hotel3_2_2"],"Town3_3":["hotel3_3_1","hotel3_3_2"],"Town3_4":["hotel3_4_1","hotel3_4_2"],"Town3_5":["hotel3_5_1","hotel3_5_2"],"Town3_6":["hotel3_6_1","hotel3_6_2"]}}};

region.innerHTML="";
var regions=Object.keys(json.regions);
regions.forEach(
  regionkey=>{
    var option=document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent=regionkey;
    region.append(option);
  }
);
changetown();
changehotel();

function changetown() {
  var selectedregion=region[region.selectedIndex].textContent;
  town.innerHTML="";
  var towns=Object.keys(json.regions[selectedregion]);
  towns.forEach(
    townkey=>{
      var option=document.createElement("option");
      option.textContent=townkey;
      town.append(option);
    }
  );
  changehotel();
}

function changehotel() {
  var selectedregion=region[region.selectedIndex].textContent;
  var selectedtown=town[town.selectedIndex].textContent;
  
  hotel.innerHTML="";
  var hotels=json.regions[selectedregion][selectedtown];
  hotels.forEach(
    hotelvalue=>{
      var option=document.createElement("option");
      option.textContent=hotelvalue;
      hotel.append(option);
    }
  );
}

function dosomething() {
  if(
    (region.selectedIndex!=-1) &&
    (town.selectedIndex!=-1) &&
    (hotel.selectedIndex!=-1)
  ) {
    var selectedregion=region[region.selectedIndex].textContent;
    var selectedtown=town[town.selectedIndex].textContent;
    var selectedhotel=hotel[hotel.selectedIndex].textContent;
  
    console.log("Final: ", selectedregion, selectedtown, selectedhotel);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="region" onchange="changetown()" ></select>
<select id="town"   onchange="changehotel()"></select>
<select id="hotel"                          ></select>
<button id="go"     onclick ="dosomething()">Go!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
const data = {regions:{region1:{
     'Town1_1':['hotel1_1_1', 'hotel1_1_2'],'Town1_2':['hotel1_2_1', 'hotel1_2_2'],'Town1_3':['hotel1_3_1', 'hotel1_3_2'],'Town1_4':['hotel1_4_1', 'hotel1_4_2'],},      'region2':{
     'Town2_1':['hotel2_1_1', 'hotel2_1_2'],'Town2_2':['hotel2_2_1', 'hotel2_2_2'],'Town2_3':['hotel2_3_1', 'hotel2_3_2'],'Town2_4':['hotel2_4_1', 'hotel2_4_2'],'Town2_5':['hotel2_5_1', 'hotel2_5_2'],},       'region3':{
     'Town3_1':['hotel3_1_1', 'hotel3_1_2'],'Town3_2':['hotel3_2_1', 'hotel3_2_2'],'Town3_3':['hotel3_3_1', 'hotel3_3_2'],'Town3_4':['hotel3_4_1', 'hotel3_4_2'],'Town3_5':['hotel3_5_1', 'hotel3_5_2'],'Town3_6':['hotel3_6_1', 'hotel3_6_2'],}
     }};
  
const mkopts=arr=>arr.map(r=>`<option>${r}</option>`).join(""),    
      sall= [...document.querySelectorAll('select')];
sall.forEach((sel,i)=>{
  if (!i) sel.innerHTML=mkopts(Object.keys(data.regions)); // initially fill first select with options
  if (i<2) {  // change options of following select whenever one of the first two changes
    sel.onchange=()=>{ let nsel=sall[i+1];
      sall[2].innerHTML=""; // clear last select box options first
      nsel.innerHTML=mkopts( // depending on situation (--> i ) get different options:
        i ?  Object.values(data.regions[sall[0].value][sall[1].value])
          :  Object.keys(data.regions[sall[0].value]) ); 
      !i && nsel.onchange();
    }
  }
});
sall[0].onchange()
```

```html
<select id='region'></select>
<select id='town'></select>
<select id='hotel'></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a bit more general solution ?

```js
var json = {'regions': {'region1': {'Town1_1': ['hotel1_1_1', 'hotel1_1_2'],'Town1_2': ['hotel1_2_1', 'hotel1_2_2'],'Town1_3': ['hotel1_3_1', 'hotel1_3_2'],'Town1_4': ['hotel1_4_1', 'hotel1_4_2'],},'region2': {'Town2_1': ['hotel2_1_1', 'hotel2_1_2'],'Town2_2': ['hotel2_2_1', 'hotel2_2_2'],'Town2_3': ['hotel2_3_1', 'hotel2_3_2'],'Town2_4': ['hotel2_4_1', 'hotel2_4_2'],'Town2_5': ['hotel2_5_1', 'hotel2_5_2'],},'region3': {'Town3_1': ['hotel3_1_1', 'hotel3_1_2'],'Town3_2': ['hotel3_2_1', 'hotel3_2_2'],'Town3_3': ['hotel3_3_1', 'hotel3_3_2'],'Town3_4': ['hotel3_4_1', 'hotel3_4_2'],'Town3_5': ['hotel3_5_1', 'hotel3_5_2'],'Town3_6': ['hotel3_6_1', 'hotel3_6_2'],},},
            'heirarchy': ['region', 'town', 'hotel']};

function updateSelects(el) {
    const heirarchy = json.heirarchy;
    let selection = json.regions;
    let level = json.heirarchy.indexOf(el);
    for(let l=0;l<=level;l++) {
        let text = document.getElementById(json.heirarchy[l]);
        text = text.options[text.selectedIndex].text;
        selection = selection[text]; // iterate selected levels
    }
    level++;
    el = document.getElementById(heirarchy[level]);
    for(var i=level;i<heirarchy.length;i++) {
        clearSelect(document.getElementById(heirarchy[i]));
    }
    for (let i in selection) {
        if (selection.constructor === Array) i = selection[i];
        var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
        opt1.innerText = i;
        el.appendChild(opt1);
    }
}

function clearSelect(el) {
    while (el.options.length) el.removeChild(el.options[0]);
}
updateSelects();
```

```html
<select id='region' onchange="updateSelects(this.id)"></select>
<select id='town' onchange="updateSelects(this.id)"></select>
<select id='hotel'></select>
```